# how to suppress the divergence or singularity message in validate function of rms package

Tags: r, validation, rms

How can I suppress the "divergence or singularity in samples" message in the **validate** function of the **rms** package. I have read the documentation, searched Harrell's 2015 book, and searched internet without success. Thank you very much. pbm

Comment: Just to be clear, your goal is to suppress the message, not treat the underlying cause?

Comment: If so, [it looks like the message is produced by `cat()`](https://github.com/harrelfe/rms/search?q=divergence+or+singularity+in+samples&unscoped_q=divergence+or+singularity+in+samples), rather than `message()` or `warning()` (which would be easy to suppress). I think `capture.output` or maybe `sink` can be used to prevent the message from printing. Let us know if you are working in an Rnw or Rmd file, as the solution may depend on that.

Comment: Just suppress the message. I am looping through 17 models with b=200 and I get the message repeatedly. pbm

Comment: I am using a .Rmd file on RStudio. pbm

Comment: With the 17 models, I get a maximum of 2 samples with divergence or singularity for every model. pbm